# AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'ArgSpec'

Tags: scrapy

I just started learning Scrapy and am debugging this example program:

```py
class EcomSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Ecom"
    allowed_domains = ["clever-lichterman-044f16.netlify.com"]
    start_urls = ['https://clever-lichterman-044f16.netlify.com/products/taba-cream.1/']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)

        l.add_xpath('price', "//div[@class='my-4']/span/text()")
        l.add_xpath("title", '//section[@class="section-sm"]//h2/text()')
        l.add_xpath("title", '//title')
        l.add_value("product_url", response.url)
        return l.load_item()`
```

```py
class Product(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()

    product_url = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    img_url = scrapy.Field()
```

When starting the program I receive an error message:

> l.add_xpath('price', "//div[@class='my-4']/span[1]/text()")
> AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'ArgSpec'

Please tell me what is the problem?

I did:

1. Rearranged l.add_xpath(...) operators
2. Changed xPath expressions

This is a tutorial and I expected there to be no problems running it.

Comment: - $ python --version
Python 3.11.5

$ scrapy version
Scrapy 2.10.1

Answer (score 3):

I share with you an error that sometimes happens when extracting data through Web Scraping using Anaconda's Jupyter Notebook and the Scrapy library:

AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'ArgSpec'

This error usually occurs when you are using a version of Scrapy that is incompatible with the version of Python or with some of the libraries that Scrapy uses internally.

I attach a solution that has worked:

**pip install --upgrade scrapy itemloaders**

I hope it can be of help to you.

All the best

Comment: - "I hope it can be of help to you."
- Yes, your advice solved the problem. Thank you very much!